# Transparency mask with vector image

Tags: graphics, opacity

Suppose we have a vector `Graphics` object, along with an arbitrary shape to use as a mask.

```
drawing =Graphics[{Point@RandomReal[{0,10},{5000,2}]}];
mask = Graphics[{Gray,Polygon[{{0, 5}, {4, 8}, {7, 8}, {9, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 2}}]}];
```

[image: input image]

Is it possible to use the mask to apply an opacity change or even an opacity gradient while maintaining the vector output of the initial drawing?

This is possible using `SetAlphaChannel`, but creates a raster image in the process.

```
SetAlphaChannel[drawing, mask]
```

[image: output image]

Comment: Here's an example where this is done on a vector drawing program: [on Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/how-to-create-a-gradient-opacity-mask-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it with computational geometry and the `Region*` functionality:

```
(* all points, as coordinates *)
coords = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {5000, 2}];

(* your polygonal mask, as a Polygon object, which can be used as a Region *)
polygonMask = Polygon[{{0, 5}, {4, 8}, {7, 8}, {9, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 2}}];

(* This generates a RegionMemberFunction object that can be applied repeatedly *)
mfun = RegionMember[polygonMask];

(* Select points within the mask *)
within = Select[coords, mfun];

(* Select points outside of the mask as the complement to the set of those within *)
outside = Complement[coords, within];

(* draw the results *)
Graphics[{Black, Point@outside, Red, Point@within}]
```

[image: red within, black outside]

For improved contrast, I made the points within the mask red, but you could use any `Graphics` styling on them.

This is the result with Opacity applied to the `within` set:

```
Graphics[{Black, Point@outside, Opacity[0.1], Point@within}]
```

[image: transparent points within]

Comment: This is a neat approach and lets me change the properties of the points themselves. Also I can generalize this from points to objects like `Circle` or `Rectangle` using e.g. `RegionWithin`.

Comment: @Musang Glad you like it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could change the mask so that it has opacity:

```
Show[drawing, mask /. Gray->GrayLevel[1,.7]]
```

[image]

Comment: I had thought of this; one drawback is that you are limited to additive effects on the points. But I see now that this accounts much more easily for objects which overlap only partially with the mask.